# Search in SQL database using array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

```
$value = array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

I have that part of query:

```
$features_filter .= $this->db->placehold('AND p.id in (SELECT product_id FROM __options WHERE feature_id=? AND value in (?@) ) ', $feature, $value);
```

That query returns result only if database contains values == 'one' or 'two' or 'three'.
How I can change my query to do that query returned some LIKE 'one' or 'two' or 'three'?

PS Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
$value = array('one', 'two', 'three');


for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($value); $i++ ):
    $new .= " LIKE '%$value[$i]%'";
    if ( $i < sizeof($value) -1 ) :
         $new .= " OR";
    endif;
endfor;

$features_filter .= $this->db->placehold('AND p.id in (SELECT product_id FROM __options WHERE feature_id=? AND value ' . $new ) ', $feature );
```

**Addition:** On PHP >= 5.3 the `for`-loop could also be replaced with this code:

```
array_walk( $value, function (&$value, $key) {
        $value = " LIKE %$value%";
   });

$new = implode(' OR', $value );
```

Comment: Thanks! PS not endforach; True is endfor;

Comment: PSS  $new .= " LIKE '%$value[$i]%'"; and $new .= " OR value";

Comment: and $features_filter .= $this->db->placehold('AND p.id in (SELECT product_id FROM __options WHERE feature_id=? AND value '.$new.' ) ', $feature);

Comment: Hope I didn't forgot anything now.